# How to create samaccountname with maximum 12 character?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to create users with max 12 characters.
The last name can contain the first 11 characters (max) + the first letter of the first name

I'm not sure what to add next to $LastName

Can you help me with this?

```
$OU = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
$PW = "Welcome$(Get-Random -minimum 0001 -maximum 9999)!"

$FirstName = Read-Host "Please enter the Firstname for the new user"
$LastName  = Read-Host "Please enter the Lastname for the new user"

$AccountName = $LastName + $FirstName[0]  # Last name (11 caracter max) + first character of first name
# test if a user with that accountname already exists and if so, append a sequence number
$count = 1
while (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$AccountName'") {
    $AccountName = '{0}{1}{2}' -f $LastName, $FirstName[0], $count++
}

$UPN = "$($FirstName).$($LastName)@domain.com" #if the upn exists, add a digit to the last name
# test if a user with that UserPrincipalName already exists and if so, append a sequence number
$count = 1
while (Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$UPN'") {
    $UPN = '{0}.{1}{2}@domain.com' -f $FirstName, $LastName, $count++
}


# create a Hashtable for splatting parameters
$userParams = @{
     Name                         = "$($LastName), $($FirstName)"
     DisplayName                  = "$($LastName), $($FirstName)"
     FirstName                    = $FirstName
     LastName                     = $LastName
     SamAccountName               = $AccountName
     OnPremisesOrganizationalUnit = $OU
     UserPrincipalName            = $UPN
     Password                     = $PW | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
     ResetPasswordOnNextLogon     = $true
     Archive                      = $true
}

# Create User On-Premise and move to the managers OU if possible
try {
    New-RemoteMailbox @userParams -ErrorAction Stop

}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: You can use `[math]:Min(11,$Lastname.Length)` to get the length of the last name up to 11, then use `$Lastname.Substring(0,[math]::Min(11,$Lastname.Length))` to get that many characters of the last name. When you start adding numbers you'll have to account for that as well.

Comment: If the account has total of 13 characters because of the added number, how can I reduce the last name by subtracting another character. Is it possible?

Comment: Change it to `[math]::Min(11,($Lastname.Length + $count.tostring().length))` inside the `while` scriptblock.

Comment: $AccountName = '{0}{1}{2}' -f $Lastname.Substring(0,[math]::Min(11,($Lastname.Length + $count.tostring().length)), $FirstName[0] doesn't work

Comment: Right, sorry, need to subtract from 11, not add to last name. This should work: `$Lastname.Substring(0,[math]::Min((11 - $count.tostring().length),$Lastname.Length))`